# Check if set of rows fall in specific values in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to check if a given table has specific column names, I want it to return true if it has them all and if one column name doesn't exist I want it to return false, this is my query :

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM db.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable'
```

I want to check if these names in the query result:
**('UpdatedDate', 'CreatedDate', 'UpdatedBy')**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know count of list this query help you

```
SELECT COUNT(COLUMN_NAME)
FROM db.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable' AND COLUMN_NAME IN ('UpdatedDate', 'CreatedDate', 'UpdatedBy')
GROUP BY COLUMN_NAME HAVING COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a table variable with the column names which we need to check with *`information_schema.columns`*. Then do a check between the table variable and *`information_schema.columns`*. Not sure how efficient is this.

**Query**

```
declare @cols as varchar(max) = 'UpdatedDate,CreatedDate,UpdatedBy';
declare @cols2 as varchar(max) = '(' + char(39);

set @cols2 += replace(@cols, ',', '''),(''') + ''');';

declare @sql as varchar(max) = 'declare @tbl as table([col] varchar(1000));';
set @sql += 'insert into @tbl values' + @cols2;
set @sql += 'declare @tot as int;set @tot = (select count(*) from @tbl);';
set @sql += 'select case when count(*) = @tot 
             then ''true'' else ''false'' end as [status] 
             from @tbl t1 where exists(
               select 1 from information_schema.columns t2 
               where t1.[col] = t2.[column_name] 
               and t2.[table_name] = ''MyTable'');';

exec(@sql);
```